# Proving the Lagrange Theorem via Bijection

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group with a neutral element $e$. Prove that for any element $g$ of $G$: $g^{|G|}=e$. $|G|$ shall be the number of elements within $G$.

Use and show that the multiplication with $g$ defines a bijection on $G$. Therefore: $\prod_{h\in G}h=\prod_{h\in G}gh$ applies!

I do not have any Idea on how to solve it, as I do not understand the idea behind all this. I found out that it has to do with the Lagrange Theorem but we did not learn that in class.  Every single hint is welcome!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please don’t use images. The site supports excellent typsetting via MathJax. [Here’s a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3):

So first we show that multiplication with $g$ is a bijection, that is, the map $h \mapsto gh$ is a bijection. We leverage basic properties of groups here:

First suppose there is $h_1, h_2$ such that $gh_1 = gh_2$. But then multiply both sides on the left with $g^{-1}$ to get $h_1 = h_2$. This gives us injectivity.

Next pick any $h \in G$. Notice then that by applying the function on $g^{-1}h$ we get that $gg^{-1}h = h$ as desired. This gives us surjectivity.

So multiplication with $g$ is in fact a bijection.

So why does this mean $\prod h = \prod gh$? Well simply because the factors in each product line up: Suppose $\prod h = h_1 \times h_2 \times \cdots \times h_{|G|}$. Then for each $h_i$, since $h \mapsto gh$ is a bijection, there is one and exactly one $h_j$ such that $h_i = gh_j$. Call this $h_j$ as $h_i'$ instead. So by doing this $|G|$ many times, we can rewrite $\prod h = h_1 \times \cdots \times h_{|G|} = gh_1' \times \cdots \times gh_{|G|}' = \prod gh$

Thus, $\prod h = \prod gh = g^{|G|}\prod h$ which implies $g^{|G|} = e$.

Comment: Thank you so much! One more Question: How do I use this bijection to disassemble (x^p-1) -1 into its irreducable Polynomials? And again thank you for your quick answer!

Comment: @tootydyhoot You mean x^(p-1)-1 not (x^p-1)-1. I assume you mean irreducible over $\Bbb F_p$, in which case all the nonzero elements are roots, so it factors as $\prod (x-k)$ where $k$ runs over $\{1,2,\cdots,p-1\}$. If you mean irreducible over $\Bbb C$, it factors as $\prod (x-\zeta)$ where $\zeta$ runs over all $n$th roots of unity. If you mean over $\Bbb Q$, that involves more work to get cyclotomic polynomials...

Answer (score 1):

Slight variation on the proof.  It's straightforward to show that multiplication by an element of $G$ defines a bijection.  Now that implies that any coset $gH$ has order $|H|$, for $H\le G$.

Next notice that being in a coset $gH$ defines an equivalence relation.  That is $g\sim h\iff gh^{-1}\in H$.  I'll leave it to you to check symmetry, reflexivity and transitivity.

As a consequence the cosets, which are all the size of $H$, partition $G$.  It follows that we can define $[G:H]:=n$ for $n=|G|/|H|$.

Now let $H=\langle g\rangle$, the cyclic subgroup generated by $g$.  Then $g^{|H|}=e$ (fairly easy).  As a result $g^{|G|}=g^{n|H|}=(g^{|H|})^n=e^n=e$.

Note that here $G$ doesn't have to be abelian.